# Where is the Administrator password for McAfee Endpoint Security stored on the local machine?

Tags: password-cracking, antivirus

> Where is the Administrator password for McAfee Endpoint Security stored on the local machine?

I've tried to locate the Administrator password for McAfee Endpoint Security in the registry on the local machine, however I cannot seem to find any hash or similar under `HKLM\SOFTWARE\McAfee`.

I have following the article https://www.pentestpartners.com/security-blog/grab-the-ui-lock-password-from-mcafee-av-kill-the-service-send-in-the-malware/, but the steps doesn't seem to work for McAfee Endpoint Security 10.5.

Any ideas where I can locate the Administrator password (hash) on the local machine?

[image]

Comment: Are you sure that the administrator password exists on the local machine at all, rather than requiring communication with a central server?

Comment: @Matthew - thank you for your suggestion. Do you know if that's the case?

Comment: No, but it's pretty common for enterprise apps, and Endpoint Security suggests it's targeting that market. Could always try monitoring the network while entering a password and clicking log on to see if any traffic is sent to a known central server, but it might have unwanted side effects (e.g. locking the account until reactivated from elsewhere)

Comment: Very likely that a local-only option exists (or is at least supported). Too many use cases and failure modes where Internet access might not be available, but antivirus needs to be disabled for legitimate reasons.